# Patch and build only one kernel module (Ubuntu 19)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, usb, kernel-module

I'm trying go get work my Boss GT-1 Guitar effect processor in Linux. I have a patch that needs to be applied to a file `sound/usb/endpoint.c` in kernel source, and recompile kernel. I succeeded in doing this on my virtual machine with Ubuntu 19.10 (full kernel compilation, install new kernel, boot into it).

Now I want to do the same on my old laptop, but a full kernel compilation takes a lot of time (~ 12 hours). I'm trying to recompile only one kernel module:

```
$ uname -r
5.3.0-29-generic
$ sudo apt-get install linux-source-5.3.0
$ cd /usr/src/
$ sudo tar -xjf linux-source-5.3.0.tar.bz2
$ cd /usr/src/linux-source-5.3.0/
$ sudo mousepad sound/usb/endpoint.c
< changing contents of file>
$ sudo make oldconfig
$ sudo cp /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-29-generic/Module.symvers ./
$ sudo make modules SUBDIRS=sound/usb
< successfully build 14 modules >
$ sudo cp sound/usb/snd-usb-audio.ko /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/kernel/sound/usb/
$ sudo depmod -a
```

After restart and boot I plug in my device, and .. nothing. dmesg says me what module version is incorrect:

```
[  183.884735] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  184.039756] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0582, idProduct=01d6, bcdDevice= 0.00
[  184.039775] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  184.039786] usb 1-1: Product: GT-1
[  184.039799] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: BOSS
[  184.180719] snd_usb_audio: version magic '5.3.13 SMP mod_unload ' should be '5.3.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload '
[  184.181005] snd_usb_audio: version magic '5.3.13 SMP mod_unload ' should be '5.3.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload '
[  184.182263] snd_usb_audio: version magic '5.3.13 SMP mod_unload ' should be '5.3.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload '
[  184.182750] snd_usb_audio: version magic '5.3.13 SMP mod_unload ' should be '5.3.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload '
```

How can I solve this? 
Is it possible to patch and make only one kernel module without recompiling full kernel sources?

Comment: If it's indeed **may** be compiled as a module (all required headers are being provided and dependencies are possible to be resolved at run-time), copy the sources of your module to some folder, create a simple Makefile (Kconfig is not needed!): `obj-m += endpoint.o` (note, it may be much more complicated if this module has a lot of source files with different config options) and run `make -C /path/to/kernel/build/headers M=$PWD modules`.